# Acceso a variables de una clase aparte

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Como puedo llamar a GetJsonList si lo pongo en una clase aparte?

Por ejemplo en mi proyecto tengo una carpeta que se llama Clases y ahi es donde tengo otras clases y esta clase cuando la pongo ahi me dice "Accesibilidad inconsistente: el tipo de propiedad 'NameMiClase' es menos accesible que la propiedad 'datos'".

Estas varibles las tengo que utilzar en otra parte de mi proyecto y no quiero andar sobre escribiendo mis varibles; si no llamarlas desde mi carpeta llamada Clases.

```
public class GetJsonList 
{
  public string dato1{ get; set; }
  public string dato2 { get; set; }
  public string dato3 { get; set; }
}
public class RootListObject
    {
        public string resultado { get; set; }
        public string mensaje { get; set; }
        public GetJsonList datos { get; set; }//aqui me marca el error cuando esta en la carpeta llamada Clases.

    }
```

De este forma deserializo el Json que recibo

```
 var msjdes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootListObject>(miJsonFormat);
```

asi asigno los datos a mis texbox:

```
 text1.Text = msjdes.datos.Dato1;
 text2.Text = msjdes.datos.Dato2;
 text3.Text = msjdes.datos.Dato3;
```

Comment: Inicializaste la clase antes de usar sus propiedades? Tienes los constructores? Los métodos get para cada propiedad?

Comment: ya hice todo eso

Comment: marca el mismo error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digamos que la estructura de tu proyecto es la siguiente:

[image: Estructura del proyecto]

En Class1.cs tienes tus clases:

```
public class GetJsonList
{
    public string dato1 { get; set; }
    public string dato2 { get; set; }
    public string dato3 { get; set; }
}
public class RootListObject
{
    public string resultado { get; set; }
    public string mensaje { get; set; }
    public GetJsonList datos { get; set; }//aqui me marca el error cuando esta en la carpeta llamada Clases.

}
```

En la clase donde quieres usar las clases de tu carpeta Clases tienes que importar tu carpeta Clases para poder utilizarlas:

```
using System;
using Borrar.Clases; //AQUI IMPORTO LA CARPETA

namespace Borrar
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RootListObject objRootListObject = new RootListObject();

            GetJsonList objGetJsonList = new GetJsonList();

            objGetJsonList.dato1 = "Dato 1";
            objGetJsonList.dato2 = "Dato 2";
            objGetJsonList.dato3 = "Dato 3";

            objRootListObject.datos = objGetJsonList;

            Console.WriteLine($"Dato 1: {objRootListObject.datos.dato1}\nDato 2: {objRootListObject.datos.dato2}\nDato 3: {objRootListObject.datos.dato3}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Entonces no hay problema con mostrar la informacion:

[image: Resultado]

Mis clases son Publicas y las utilizo dentro de una clase privada al llamarlas.